# AWS RDS: specifying lc_collate and lc_ctype for PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to create a PostgreSQL database on RDS using CloudFormation. It says that all supported parameters are described in [CreateDBInstance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDBInstance.html). So far I have been unable to find any parameter there or via the DB parameter groups that influences `LC_COLLATE` or `LC_CTYPE`. Those need to be specified during database creation and cannot be changed afterwards.

Right now both values will always be set to `en_US.UTF-8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create database specifying those, eg:

```
t=# create database c LC_COLLATE 'C' LC_CTYPE 'C' template template0;
CREATE DATABASE
t=# \l+
                                                                    List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   |  Size   | Tablespace |                Description
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------+---------+------------+--------------------------------------------
 c         | postgres | UTF8     | C           | C           |                       | 7601 kB | pg_default |
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |                       | 8157 kB | pg_default | default administrative connection database
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +| 7601 kB | pg_default | unmodifiable empty database
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres |         |            |
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +| 7733 kB | pg_default | default template for new databases
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres |         |            |
(4 rows)
```

Comment: I had hoped that maybe I could have the DB that's being created by default to have the correct configuration. Looks like my best solution is to have an init script that drops it and recreates it.